# DSUM won't let me give it criteria

Tags: ms-access

I have a few tables: Order, OrderLine, and Cost being relevant here.

In my Order entry form, I have two subforms, one for OrderLine and one for Cost. At the footer, I have a "subtotal" which I simply want to sum up my extended prices on my orderline sub form. I tried doing something like this:

```
=Sum([OrderLine subform].[Form]![PriceExtended])
```

But it gives me an `#Error` (without ever telling me the error anywhere, that's another annoying problem...) Well, okay that's not a problem we can just go straight to the database with it. So I tried using DSUM like so

```
=DSum("PriceExtended","OrderLine","OrderUnique=" & [OrderUnique])
```

And that gave me an error and it just made the box blink... well okay it's not picking up the OrderUnique field, so we'll try hardcoding it

```
=DSum("PriceExtended","OrderLine","OrderUnique=SHOP1234")
```

Nope, still giving me the stupid blinking... okay then, let's try no criteria

```
=DSum("PriceExtended","OrderLine")
```

And that works just fine, except of course it sums up every order ever and I only want to sum up the lines for this particular order.

So why would my DSum criteria not accept "OrderUnique=SHOP1234"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since OrderUnique is defined as a Text field, you need to surround the value with single quotes or double quotes. You want the criteria string to look like:

```
OrderUnique='SHOP1234'
```

, so you would hard code that as

```
=DSum("PriceExtended","OrderLine","OrderUnique='SHOP1234'")
```

or build it with

```
=DSum("PriceExtended","OrderLine","OrderUnique='" & [OrderUnique] & "'")
```

Comment: I'm just glad your sample happened to have alpha characters in it. It's much tougher error to spot if a text field has only numerals in it, like `OrderUnique=1234`.